# Creating windows firewall outbound rule for Google Chrome to not access a specific port

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, windows-firewall

I am trying to disallow my Chrome browser to access a specific port on a remote machine.
To be more clear: I want e.g. Opera to be able to access the TCP port 1850 but i want to block Chrome on TCP port 1850.

With Firefox i could choose the path wich resulted in:

```
%ProgramFiles% (x86)\Mozilla Firefox 4.0 Beta 1\plugin-container.exe
```

I chose the port to block and it worked.

When I chose chrome (which  process manager tells me runs in my AppData directory the path is

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

and set the (same) port it does not block the connection.

Any ideas why?

OS: Windows 7 Home Premium (German)

Comment: The actual problem was to use the variable %USERPROFILE% in the path, if this is replaced by the real path the rule works. This is also stated in the Windows help documentation, but who is looking there for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to block?

Using the Windows Firewall and creating an outbound rule to disable, let's say, port 443 on remote machines, I can no longer connect to any https connection on remote servers. Maybe you chose the wrong protocol.

Comment: The port i am blocking ist 1850 and it works with the firefox rule AND it works if i choose to block any application not only chrome...

Comment: So to understand what you want: Your server works on TCP protocol with port number 1850. You want Chrome to not work on that port. I don't know what Service you are connecting to, but comparing it to your Firefox line, you might use a specific non-flash plugin. I would recommend looking for the plugin you use in about:memory and look for the pid. Use the pid to look up the exact system call in the task manager (or process explorer from sysinternals), the calls might be hidden by a chrome.exe wrapper and not work properly. It's also possible that the process you want to block isnt chrome at all

Comment: This MUST be a rule for chrome then, because the firefox rule works.(?)

Comment: OK i found something in the help (!) unfortunately in german but in short it says you should not use variables like %USERPROFILE%

Comment: Yes, but still figure out what I wrote you. Chrome handles plugins differently than Firefox, as Firefox uses the plugin container, but I'm not quite sure how Chrome handles it.

Comment: Please tell if the userprofile-help entry helped you, or continue to explain your experience with the 2nd comment

Comment: if you allow my edits on your answer it is solved for me... as for the path itself: it appears that google creates a process for every tab (including the plugin, flash in my case)

Answer (score -1):

I understand your question to be why is Chrome listed as being installed in your %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local directory.

This is how Google designed their application.  To have Chrome install to your Program Files folder as a more typical (and less virus looking) application you must install Chrome via the [Google Pack](http://pack.google.com/intl/en/pack_installer.html) download (which allows one install process to install one or more Google software titles) or use the [Google Chrome MSI installer](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?msi=true).

Comment: I am fine with the install location as long as this is not the reason for the firewall to NOT block the chosen port.